# GWT: Unable to find GWTModule/gwt/xml.gwt.xml

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-plugin

When I try to compile an Eclipse Dynamic Web Application that uses GWT, I get the following error message:

> [ERROR] Unable to find
>   'GWTModule/gwt/xml.gwt.xml' on your
>   classpath; could be a typo, or maybe
>   you forgot to include a classpath
>   entry for source?

I can't figure out what is causing this problem. 
My Eclipse build path contains next to some other GWT-unrelated jars/libs the GWT SDK (2.1.0).

My GWTModule.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.1.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.1.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <source path="client"/>
    <entry-point class="gwttest.ui.client.TestUI" />
</module>
```

The environments classpath variable is not set, because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075839/gwt-eclipse-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gwt-dev-compiler)

I encountered a similar problem with a completely new GWT project, but there the project could be compiled - the error message showed up at runtime in the GWT log...

My System:

- Windows XP
- Eclipse for Java EE 3.6 (Helios) with GWT plugin
- GWT 2.1.0
- Java EE / JDK 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Your `GWTModule.xml` should be `GWTModule.gwt.xml` unless that's an error in your question.

Comment: Oh my mistake. The file name is GWTModule.gwt.xml. I am wondering why the compiler is looking for a xml.gwt.xml file, there is no such file in any GWT project I create