# GWT compilation error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am struggling hard to compile a GWT project. I confirmed that GWT, AppEngine and necessary library are referenced to the project *(added in the **Java Build Path**, also GWT is installed successfully from Marketplace)*.

Using the setting above, I tried to build using GWT and I have been getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/Compiler

over and over again.

Then tried to set **gwt-dev.jar** in **Windows CLASSPATH**, and I could get off from this error but ended up with

> [ERROR] Unable to find 'some/package/My_Project.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

I tried to set project classpath to `some/package/` but didn't work.

Even I could manage to get over with this error ***for once***, again I got into another error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/enhancer/Enhance.

I screwed up the environment and couldn't get to the last error I was getting, and I was just stuck on the second error.

I have tried removing all Run Configuration, creating new workspace and import projects from scratch and tried everything that I found on Google.

Comment: Re: "I tried to set project classpath to `some/package/` but didn't work": when it complains that it can't find `some/package/My_Project.gwt.xml` in the classpath, it's because the directory *containing* `some` isn't on your classpath.

Comment: I have also confirmed that _directory containing *some*_ is in project's classpath

Comment: Jesus, don't touch the Windows Classpath for this

Comment: Later, I removed it from Classpath, still ending up with `NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/Compiler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at this answer: [GWT/ Eclipse: ClassNotFoundException com/google/gwt/dev/Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075839/gwt-eclipse-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gwt-dev-compiler)

Also, you can try to clean your project and add the jar file via the usual class path configuration within eclipse (right click on your project). You can then add the gwt-dev.jar file from the plugin. Make sure you use the one that was installed in the plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! I renamed `Classpath` to `__Classpath` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

`[ERROR]` `Unable to find 'some/package/My_Project.gwt.xml' on your`

`classpath`; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a `classpath`

entry for source?

Check out the link for more info...[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-4/wiki/FAQ_UnableToFindModule)